# Why does ylim not have the desired effects on my plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The ylim parameter does not have the desired effect on the accuracy plot. Calling set_ylim on the axes[0] does have the same effect.

My code looks like this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10,8))
axes[0].plot(df['Acc'], "g--", label="Accuracy of training data")
axes[0].plot(df['Val_acc'], "g", label="Accuracy of validation data")
axes[0].set(title="Accuracy",
            ylabel="Accuracy",
            xlabel="Epochs",
            ylim=[0,1],
            xlim=[0, len(df)-1])
axes[0].legend(loc="best")
axes[1].plot(df['Loss'], "r--", label="Loss of training data")
axes[1].plot(df['Val_loss'], "r", label="Loss of validation data")
axes[1].set(title="Loss",
            ylabel="Loss",
            xlabel="Epochs",
            xlim=[0, len(df)-1])
axes[1].legend(loc="best")
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('model4.png', dpi=300)
```

[image: Faulty_plot]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT: Trying to come up with a short, reproducible example ylim works (and the values for the loss plot are not scrambled up anymore as pointed out by @Sheldore).

```
test_index = np.arange(1,11)
test_columns = ['Acc', 'Loss', 'Val_loss', 'Val_acc']
df_test = pd.DataFrame(index=test_index, columns=test_columns)
df_test['Acc'] = np.array([0.5007, 0.4984, 0.4991, 0.4982, 0.4941, 0.5043, 0.4971, 0.4975, 0.4966, 0.4992])
df_test['Loss'] = np.array([0.6940, 0.6937, 0.6933, 0.6932, 0.6947, 0.6932, 0.6932, 0.6932, 0.6932, 0.6932])
df_test['Val_loss'] = np.array([0.6934, 0.6931, 0.6932, 0.6931, 0.6929, 0.6931, 0.6932, 0.6932, 0.6931, 0.6934])
df_test['Val_acc'] = np.array([0.4935, 0.5065, 0.4935, 0.5112, 0.5017, 0.5065, 0.4935, 0.4935, 0.4935, 0.4935])
df_test.head()



fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(10,8))
axes[0].plot(df_test['Acc'], "g--", label="Accuracy of training data")
axes[0].plot(df_test['Val_acc'], "g", label="Accuracy of validation data")
axes[0].set(title="Accuracy",
            ylabel="Accuracy",
            xlabel="Epochs",
            ylim=[0,1],
            xlim=[1, len(df_test)-1])
#axes[0].set_ylim([0,1])
axes[0].legend(loc="best")
axes[1].plot(df_test['Loss'], "r--", label="Loss of training data")
axes[1].plot(df_test['Val_loss'], "r", label="Loss of validation data")
axes[1].set(title="Loss",
            ylabel="Loss",
            xlabel="Epochs",
            xlim=[1, len(df_test)-1])
axes[1].legend(loc="best")
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('test_model.png', dpi=300)
```

[image: Test model from minimal example]

Comment: Looking at the mixed up order of y-ticklabels in your figures, it seems your y-values are strings. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Sheldore Unfortunately I can not. If I create the Dataframe manually with the first ten values, ylim works and the values for the Loss plot are not scrambled. See edit. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Can you check the data type of your `df_test['Acc']` by doing `print (type(df_test['Acc'][0]))`? What do you get?

Comment: Thank you very much, it is `<class 'str'>` I had to parse the values from txt, but I thought np.asarray would include the conversion to floats. `df = df.astype(float)` did the trick :)